# Do I need to manually VACUUM temporary tables in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, temp-tables

Consider I have an application server which:

- uses connection pooling (with a relatively high number of allowed idle connections),
- can run for months, and
- makes heavy use of temporary tables (which are not `DROP`'ped on `COMMIT`).

The above means that I may have *N* "eternal" database sessions "holding" *N* temporary tables, which will only be dropped when the server is restarted.

I'm well aware that the autovacuum daemon can't access those temporary tables.

My question is, if I make frequent `INSERT`'s to and `DELETE`'s from temporary tables, and the tables are supposed to "live" for a long time, then do I need to manually `VACUUM` those tables after a deletion, or a single manual `ANALYZE` would be enough?

Currently, if I execute

```
select
  n_tup_del,
  n_live_tup,
  n_dead_tup,
  n_mod_since_analyze,
  vacuum_count,
  analyze_count
from
  pg_stat_user_tables
where
  relname = '...'
order by
  n_dead_tup desc;
```

I see the that `vacuum_count` is always zero:

```
n_tup_del   n_live_tup  n_dead_tup  n_mod_since_analyze vacuum_count    analyze_count
64      3       64      0           0       16
50      1       50      26          0       3
28      1       28      2           0       5
7       1       7       4           0       4
3       1       3       2           0       4
1       6       1       8           0       2
0       0       0       0           0       0
```

which may mean that manual `VACUUM` is indeed required.

Comment: analyze will gather stats on the table, while vacuum (possibly) release the space

Comment: @VaoTsun Apparently, so, but I'm looking for the confirmation. The documentation seems unclear.

Comment: I quoted man in answer. but I don't understand the question. they server different goals, just vacuum can optionally also analyze. so its up to you if you want it or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-commands.html

> ANALYZE — collect statistics about a database
>
> VACUUM — garbage-collect
>   and optionally analyze a database

vacuum can optionaly also analyze. So if all you want - fresh stats - just `analyze`. If you want to "recover" unused rows, then `vacuum`. I f you want both, use `vacuum analyze`

Answer (score 2):

We had and application which was running for 24+ hours using a lot of long living quite heavy updated temp tables and we used ANALYZE on them. But there is a problem with VACUUM - if you try to use in function you get an error:

```
ERROR:  VACUUM cannot be executed from a function or multi-command string
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "vacuum xxxxxx"
PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 4 at SQL statement
SQL state: 25001
```

But later we discovered, that temp tables actually were not so advantageous at least for our app. Technically they are normal tables existing as datafiles on disk in so called temporary tablespace (either pg_default or you can set it in postgresql.conf file). But they use only so called temp_buffers - they are not loaded into shared_buffers. So you have to set temp_buffers properly and rely more on Linux cache. And as you already mentioned - autovacuum daemon "does not see" them. Therefore we later switched to using normal tables.